# Check if number is already in field before concatenating?

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a crawler that scans many urls and then puts all the words found in each webpage into a table. In this same table the `ID` of the url is stored. If the word is repeated in another page, the `ID` of the url the word was found on is concatenated with a comma separating them. So if a word appears on multiple pages, all the concatenated `ID` numbers in the field might look like:

```
2,3,6,8,9
```

At the moment, if the number appears multiple times on the same page, the `ID` number will be added each time the number is found so the `URLID` field might end up looking like:

```
2,2,2,4,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9
```

Using `Java` is there a way I get it to check if the number exists in the field already and only add it if it is not already there? I have looked through the api but cannot seem to find a suitable way to do this. Any ideas?

---

Addition:

```
public void updateWordTable( String[] array, int urlid ) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
    String wordQuery;
    String query;


    for (String item : array) {
        if(item.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")){
            wordQuery = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE word = '"+item+"'";
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(wordQuery);
            if(!rs.next()){
                query = "INSERT INTO word VALUES ('"+item+"',"+urlid+")";
                stat.executeUpdate( query );
            }
            else {
                //query = "UPDATE word SET urlid = concat(urlid, ',"+urlid+"') WHERE word = '"+item+"' ";
                //query = "UPDATE word SET urlid = CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( '"+urlid+"', urlid ) > 0 THEN urlid ELSE CONCAT( urlid, ',', '"+urlid+"' )END WHERE word = '"+item+"' ";

                String query2 = "UPDATE word SET urlid = CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( ?, urlid ) > 0 THEN urlid ELSE CONCAT( urlid, ',', ? )END WHERE word = ? ";

                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement( query2 );

                pst.setLong( 1, urlid );
                pst.setLong( 2, urlid );
                pst.setString( 3, item);

                int result = pst.executeUpdate();

                //stat.executeUpdate( query2 );
            }
        }
    }

    stat.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *... is there a way I get it to check if the number exists in the field already and only add it if it is not already there?*

You can do it using JAVA, but leave that checking to MySQL as it has such search features.

Using MySQL, you can use `FIND_IN_SET` function on comma separated values in the column. This will solve your problem to not reprocess in JAVA to find if such id exists.

```
select 
  FIND_IN_SET( value_to_find, column_with_cs_values ) > 0 as bool_matched
from table_name
```

Add `where` condition and others if any required.

And in the JAVA code you can just read the resultset for `getBoolean`.

```
boolean idMatched = rs.getBoolean( "bool_matched" );

if( idMatched ) {
  // dont update table
}
else {
  // update table
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can directly `update` the table column.

**Example**:

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET column_name_with_cs_values = 
        CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( value_to_find, 
                               column_name_with_cs_values 
                  ) > 0 THEN column_name_with_cs_values 
             ELSE CONCAT( column_name_with_cs_values, ',', value_to_find )
        END
-- add where etc here
;
```

In JAVA, you can use the above query like the following with `PreparedStatement`.

```
String query = "UPDATE word 
                SET urlid = CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( ?, urlid ) > 0 THEN urlid 
                            ELSE CONCAT( urlid, ',', ? )
                            END 
                WHERE word = ? ";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( query );

pst.setString( 1, urlid );
pst.setString( 2, urlid );
pst.setString( 3, item);

int result = pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I am using your alternate method, and it works except for the fact that every field of every row has the urlid. For example if the word "hello" was found in pages with the following urls:
`2,3,4,5,7,9`
Then every single row would now have `2,3,4,5,7,9` in it. Does this suggest that it is not evaluating the WHERE part of the query? Here is the query I am using:
`query = "UPDATE word SET urlid = CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( '"+urlid+"', urlid ) > 0 THEN urlid ELSE CONCAT( urlid, ',', '"+urlid+"' )END WHERE word = '"+item+"' ";`

Comment: The word in variable `'item'` a full text or part of text from the field `word`? If it is part of the field, then you have to use `where word like '%" + item + "%' ";`

Comment: And use `PreparedStatement` to place values into the query. But not string concatenation.

Comment: 'item' is the word in the 'word' field so it will be the full text. And can you explain what you mean by "And use PreparedStatement to place values into the query. But not string concatenation. " Sorry I am fairly new to Mysql! I really appreciate the help by the way

Comment: Check my updated answer with example on usage of `PreparedStatement`

Comment: What is the variable result? Is either 1 or 0 which I imagine are the return values of pst.executeUpdate()?

Comment: Yes. It is the count of records affected after executing the statement.

Comment: So the number of duplicate values found?

Comment: Then, due to the update condition used, though update is performed, it affects no rows and returns a `0`.

Comment: So am I using result for anything?

Comment: Also it gives me the following error when I try to run: 

"You have an error in your SQL syntax;" 


The error is with the query string

Comment: OK. You have to use correct `table_name` after `update`. Currently it is like `update word`. I believe, `word` is not the table name.

Comment: I don't see any error in the query I proposed. Can you post how you used it in java and values used for parameters?

Comment: And, can you append them to your post than pasting in the comments area?

Comment: Sure, I have my if statement checking if the word is in the table, if it is not, execute code inserting it. The else part, meaning the ID is already in the table, has the following code:
`String query2 = "UPDATE word SET urlid = CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET( ?, urlid ) > 0 THEN urlid ELSE CONCAT( urlid, ',', ? )END WHERE word = ? ";

     PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement( query2 );
  
     pst.setLong( 1, urlid );
     pst.setLong( 2, urlid );
     pst.setString( 3, item);
  
     int result = pst.executeUpdate();
     
     stat.executeUpdate( query2 );`

Comment: Why `stat.executeUpdate( query2 );` again? Remove that statement and execute.

Comment: And, as I suggested in my previous comment, add your `java` code to your question. Please add both `if` and `else` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your values are stored in mysql because your question is tagged mysql. In java you can request your database with a select and check if the value is already inserted.

Or if your are not in the mysql world but only java, use a structure that give you the guartantee of unicity as a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer with that! I am storing the values in a mysql database.

Comment: So before Inserting, check if the values are already stored with a Select statement.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have tried using a select statement but I am unsure what to use for the WHERE parameter. For example if I was using WHERE urlid = "2", the row with the following field would not be returned:
2,2,2,3,3
I would need to use WHERE url = "2,2,2,3,3" if I wanted that row.

Comment: You can use LIKE. WHERE urlid LIKE '%2%'. I will return if the urlid field contains 2

Comment: @Thomas: No. `Like '%2%' results true on values like `12`, `2`, `32`, `1020` etc but not just `2` it self. Which is not correct.

Comment: So use LIKE '%2,%' with a comma. You have to think a bit by yourself. I'm just giving your hints to get you out of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just to load those values into Set. Set will take case to have unique elements only.
The idea is whenever you store your IDs this structure should keep uniqueness. Set is the best one when we talk about Java.
If you would like to have some mechanism on database to provide uniqueness that's another story.
That's just the general tip.

Comment: Or just use Hibernate object containing HashSet. And in this Set store your IDs. Hibernate will be mapped to your database table providing uniqueness by Set.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a String then you can use regex

```
    boolean exists = s.matches("(^|.*,)"+ n + "($|,.*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Store new url_id in temp variable.

Step2: now check this url_id existence in your table by select statement, you can do this by below query, suppose new url_id is 7:

```
SELECT COUNT(url_id) FROM mytable WHERE (url_id LIKE '7,%' OR url_id LIKE '%,7' OR url_id LIKE '%,7,%');
```

Step3: if you get any count from above query then leave it, otherwise add in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a project coded in pl/sql that comes across the case like yours. My variable is stored in a String and I have to check if the number was already in the String variable. I did it from using

```
   IF instr('2,3,6,8,9,' '2,') <= 0 THEN
     ' Code to append the '2,'
   End If
```

For JAVA there is something similar to instr method, String.indexOf()

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm

However note that it will return 0 if it's the first character, so probably it will be < 0

```
String a = "2,3,6,8,9,";
If a.indexOf(ID + ",") < 0 { // -1 equivalent to NOT FOUND
    // code to append ID + ","; 
}
```

Note I need to check on ID + "," reason is e.g.

```
ID = "2";
a = "20,3,6,8,9,";
```

It will return me 0 due to the 20. Therefore I'm using comma as a delimiter for every number found.

So after I finish append variable a, I would remove the last comma by

```
a = a.substring(0, a.length()-1); // this will remove the last ","
System.out.println(a); // the output should be - 2,3,6,8,9
```

This is using Java if your variable is stored in Java.